# How to cancel "EditMode" in asp.net formview when the user moves to another part of the aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on an asp.net c# web forms application using Visual Studio 2013.

When a row is selected in a gridview, the details for that row display below the gridview in a formview.  When the user clicks "Edit", the form enters EditMode as anticipated.  However, if the user moves to another part of the page and begins working in another area away from the formview, it remains in EditMode.  How can I force "Cancel" on the formview if the user removes focus from the formview?

Here is the code for the gridview and formview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_vendor_contacts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="vendor_contact_id_pk" DataSourceID="sdc_gv_vendor_contacts" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="vendor_contact_ln" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="vendor_contact_ln"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="vendor_contact_fn" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="vendor_contact_fn"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="vendor_contact_em" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="vendor_contact_em"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="vendor_contact_ph" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="vendor_contact_ph"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField Visible="false" DataField="vendor_contact_primary_yn" HeaderText="Primary Contact" SortExpression="vendor_contact_primary_yn"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="yn" HeaderText="Primary Contact" SortExpression="yn" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#BCC7D9" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#044C92" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#044C92" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle CssClass="gv_padding" BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="gv_padding" BackColor="#BCC7D9" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code for the formview:

```
<asp:FormView OnItemUpdated="fv_vendor_contact_details_ItemUpdated" ID="fv_vendor_contact_details" Width="100%" runat="server" DataKeyNames="vendor_contact_id_pk" DataSourceID="sdc_fv_vendor_contact_details">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <%--vendor_contact_id_pk:--%>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Last Name:</strong><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_ln") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_lnTextBox" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>First Name:</strong><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_fn") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_fnTextBox" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <strong>Email:</strong><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_em") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_emTextBox" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Phone:</strong><br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_ph") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_phTextBox" />
                </div>  

                <%--SDC for primary contact ddl--%>
                <asp:SqlDataSource 
                    ID="sdc_vendor_contact_primary_yn" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:idrfConnectionString %>' 
                    SelectCommand="
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                    yn_id_pk
                    , yn
                    , tbl_vendor_contact.vendor_contact_primary_yn
                    FROM tbl_yn_list
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_vendor_contact 
                    ON tbl_yn_list.yn_id_pk = tbl_vendor_contact.vendor_contact_primary_yn
                    GROUP BY yn_id_pk, yn, tbl_vendor_contact.vendor_contact_primary_yn">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Primary Contact:</strong><br />
                    <asp:DropDownList
                        ID="vendor_contact_primary_yn_ddl"
                        runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="sdc_vendor_contact_primary_yn" 
                        DataTextField="yn" 
                        DataValueField="yn_id_pk"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_primary_yn") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <%--<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_primary_yn") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_primary_ynTextBox"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <asp:Label Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("vendor_contact_id_pk") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_id_pkLabel1" />
                </div>              
            </div>
            <%--vendor_id_fk:--%>
            <asp:TextBox ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("vendor_id_fk") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_id_fkTextBox" /><br />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%--vendor_contact_id_pk:--%>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("vendor_contact_id_pk") %>' Visible="false" runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_id_pkLabel" /><br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Last Name:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_ln") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_lnLabel" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>First Name:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_fn") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_fnLabel" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <strong>Email:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_em") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_emLabel" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Phone:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_ph") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_phLabel" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <strong>Primary Contact:</strong><br />
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_contact_primary_yn") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_primary_ynLabel" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("yn") %>' runat="server" ID="vendor_contact_primary_yn_lbl"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>


            <%--vendor_id_fk:--%>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("vendor_id_fk") %>' Visible="false" runat="server" ID="vendor_id_fkLabel" /><br />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Can you please elaborate "if the user moves to another part of the page"? Another part, itself is a broad term, you must mention or invoke some particular event / control such as GridView, TextBox etc.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  The page has 2 gridviews and 4 textboxes along with the formview.  If the user clicks on any part of the gridviews or on any of the 4 textboxes I would like to cancel the EditMode for the this formview.

Comment: I added fv_vendor_contact_details.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly); to each of the gridviews selectedindexchanged and and it works.  When the user clicks on either of these the mode changes as expected.  I'll try the 4 textboxes next.  If they work I'll post the results.

Comment: In case of TextBox you do not have much options, only `TextChanged` could be tapped. IMO click won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement / suitability you can tap any event of those other controls that initiates a **postback**, such as `TextChanged` event for the `TextBox`, `SelectedIndexChanging` or `Sorting` or `PageIndexChanging` event for `GridView`.

On post back on these events you may check your form view state. If it is in edit mode then you may cancel it.

Event selection would largely depend on your approach and coding style. Such as whether you use `RowSelection`, `Sorting` feature for `GridView` or not.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent help.  The information you provided has got me thinking about all of the different ways I can make this happen. I'm reviewing the event selections now.